# Similar matrices are corresponding to the same linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $T:V\to W$, where $\dim V=\dim W$(both finite), $\beta,\beta'$ be bases of $V$, $\gamma,\gamma'$ be bases of $W$. We know that $[T]_\beta^\gamma$ and $[T]_{\beta'}^{\gamma'}$ are similar. However, given two matrices, say $A,~B$. If they are similar, I know that $A$ must  corresponding to some linear transformation $T$ from some vector space $V$ to $W$, with respect to some bases $\beta$ and $\gamma$, namely $A=[T]_\beta^\gamma$ for some $T,\beta,\gamma$. However, how can I show that $B$ also corresponding to this **same** $T:V\to W$, but different bases $\beta'$ and $\gamma'$? How to show that? Or did I get wrong in the beginning- that we should not prove this fact as this way? Thanks!

Comment: $\dim V < \infty$?

Comment: Yes. Both are finite-dimensional

Comment: Well, intuitively, if $A=PBP^{-1}$, then you change the basis to the columns of $P$, apply $B$, change the basis back, and obtain $A$.

Comment: So I need to actually use the change of coordinate matrix, say $\begin{bmatrix}3&1&4\\0&4&5\\1&5&5\end{bmatrix}$ to calculate what $\beta'$ would be, from the $\beta$ we already have?